# HD Phone resizes window when a trigger is activated

Tags: jquery, meta, device

I have a navigation slide that when triggered, it pushes a div (.page) containing all content aside to make way for it to appear. It works as intended on a resized desktop browser and on small resolution phones. The issue is with bigger resolution phones. Instead of pushing the .page aside, it resizes the window until it contains the slide and the .page on the screen. And although html and body have 100% height they resize to half of that, the rest of the phone screen is empty. I don't understand why that is happening.

My html has the meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=600, maximum-scale=1" />
```

This is my CSS:

```
html {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

body {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-image: url('../img/bg_landing.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/bg_landing.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/bg_landing.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}

.page {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

body.slided {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

And this is my js:

```
var ww = $(window).width();
var triggerw = $('#trigger').outerWidth();
var allowed_w = ww - Number(triggerw) - 20;

$('#nav').css('left', -allowed_w);

$('#trigger').click(function() {
    ww = $(window).width();
    allowed_w = ww - Number(triggerw) - 20;

    if($('.page').hasClass('slided')) {
        $('.page').animate({
            'margin-left' : '0px'
        }).removeClass('slided');

        $('#nav').animate({
            'left' : -allowed_w - 5
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.page').animate({
            'margin-left' : allowed_w
        }).addClass('slided');

        $('#nav').animate({
            'left' : '0px',
            'width': allowed_w
        });
    }
});
```

I can't post images because I don't have enough reputation, but here's a link with the print screen. The dark part of the screenshot is still part of the phone screen.

[Image on tinypic](http://i59.tinypic.com/21o6h6c.png)!

Let me know if you require additional info.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Hi, added a link with the screenshot, since I can't post images yet.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to bypass the auto resizing by not allowing user scaling.
Below is my new meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=600, user-scalable=no" />
```

If anyone can make another suggestion on how this can be done better, let me know.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Right now, it's reversed. The smaller phone is the issue now.